# How to remove all characters before a specific character in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'd like to remove all characters before a designated character or set of characters (for example):

```
intro = "<>I'm Tom."
```

Now I'd like to remove the `<>` before `I'm` (or more specifically, `I`). Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the designated character?

Comment: @SimeonVisser In this case, it's `I`.

Comment: I get that but in other cases? How do we know where the text starts?

Comment: Well, I'm filtering through what I'm looking for in the text; so in response, you'd know where it starts by using loops, splitting text/words, etc.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `re.sub`. Just match all the chars upto `I` then replace the matched chars with `I`.

```
re.sub(r'^.*?I', 'I', stri)
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to `re`, I'll look into it some more; I appreciate the answer, thanks!

Comment: note that, you may switch between first or last `I` `re.sub(r'.*?I', 'I', stri)`. But other answer won't satisfy this.

Comment: So you're saying `re` is the best option? Do you have any good tutorials/articles explaining the fundamentals of `re`? And thanks for your help.

Comment: Choosing the answer is all upto you. Yeh, learning regex is a must one for every developer since there are only few languages which won't use regex.

Comment: @AvinashRajdo you know how I could do this without knowing the length or characters?

Comment: @CoderPE you can use my answer which won't expect you to know the chars length.

Comment: Won't this remove all characters before the last "I"? Not all characters before the first "I"?

Comment: missing `import re`

Comment: input and output strings are not properly indicated: `output_str = re.sub(r'^.*?I', 'I', input_str)`

Answer (score 52):

`str.find` could find character index of `certain string's first appearance`:

```
intro[intro.find('I'):]
```

Comment: If the character is missing from the string, this will return just the last character of the input string because `.find` will return `-1` and `some_str[-1:]` is "return all characters starting from the last one".

Comment: Thank you that help me partially. Also if want to remove all characters before/with founded character index:
`intro[intro.find('I')+1:]`

Answer (score 32):

Since `index(char)` gets you the first index of the character, you can simply do `string[index(char):]`.

For example, in this case `index("I") = 2`, and `intro[2:] = "I'm Tom."`

Comment: No problem. This will work for any string as well. Note that 1) You will probably have to make sure the index is valid, i.e. not -1 and 2)   `index` only returns the first occurrence of the given string.

Comment: Actual example would be: `intro[intro.index('I'):]`

Comment: This will raise a  `ValueError` if the character doesn't appear in the string.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the character position of where to start deleting, you can use slice notation:

```
intro = intro[2:]
```

Instead of knowing where to start, if you know the characters to remove then you could use the [lstrip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) function:

```
intro = intro.lstrip("<>")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "<>I'm Tom."
temp = str.split("I",1)
temp[0]=temp[0].replace("<>","")
str = "I".join(temp)
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but you may use this `'I' + intro.split('I', 1)[1]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Neither am I, though how (genuinely curious) would this shape the function differently? In my understanding, you're splitting everything before the `I`? As well as, what does the `[1]` represent?

Comment: Index 1 of the splitted list

Answer (score 2):

I looped through the string and passed the index.

```
intro_list = []

intro = "<>I'm Tom."
for i in range(len(intro)):
    if intro[i] == '<' or intro[i] == '>':
        pass
    else:
        intro_list.append(intro[i])

intro = ''.join(intro_list)
print(intro)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

date_div = "Blah blah\nblah, Updated: Aug. 23, 2012 Blah blah Updated: Feb. 13, 2019"

up_to_word = ":"
rx_to_first = r'^.*?{}'.format(re.escape(up_to_word))
rx_to_last = r'^.*{}'.format(re.escape(up_to_word))

# (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. 
# If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

print("Remove all up to the first occurrence of the word including it:")
print(re.sub(rx_to_first, '', date_div, flags=re.DOTALL).strip())

print("Remove all up to the last occurrence of the word including it:")
print(re.sub(rx_to_last, '', date_div, flags=re.DOTALL).strip())
```

Comment: How would I keep the first and last occurence in this approach?

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> intro = "<>I'm Tom."
#Just split the string at the special symbol

>>> intro.split("<>")

Output = ['', "I'm Tom."]

>>> new = intro.split("<>")

>>> new[1]
"I'm Tom."
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @AvinashRaj answer, you can use re.sub to substituate a substring by a string or a character thanks to regex:

```
import re

output_str = re.sub(r'^.*?I', 'I', input_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works if the character is not in the string too, but uses if statements which can be slow.

```
if 'I' in intro:
  print('I' + intro.split('I')[1])
else:
  print(intro)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to all the characters before seeing a character to stop at. Then, you can use `''.join()` to turn the resulting iterable back into a string:

```py
from itertools import dropwhile
''.join(dropwhile(lambda x: x not in stop, intro))
```

This outputs:

```
I'm Tom.
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import re
intro = "<>I'm Tom."
re.sub(r'<>I', 'I', intro)
```

Comment: doesn't remove everything before a designated character (OP), e.g. with `intro = "junk<>I'm Tom."`, yields `"junkI'm Tom."`