# How to remove specific characters in front of another specific character?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

In the string:

```
my_string = 'log   (x)'
```

I need to remove all spaces `' '` in front of left parentheses `'('`

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945784/how-to-remove-all-characters-before-a-specific-character-in-python) suggests using:

```
re.sub(r'.*(', '(', my_string)
```

which is an overkill because it has the same effect as `my_string[my_string.index('('):]` and removes also `'log'`

Is there some regexpr magic to remove all spaces in front of another specific character?

Comment: Are you writing a parser? Consider using a peg instead of regex

Comment: Both rednaw and Jean-Francois' solutions solve my case . Accepting JF's for the non-re based version if that makes sense, let me know if you'd suggest otherwise.

Comment: fafl, yes sort of a parser, could you elaborate on the peg, pls?

Comment: [Parsing Expression Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)

Comment: pyPEG should be what you are looking for: https://fdik.org/pyPEG1/#sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use *forward lookahead*:

```
re.sub(r"\s+(?=\()","",my_string)
```

the entity between parentheses is not consumed (not replaced) thanks to `?=` operator, and `\s+` matches any number of whitespace (tab, space, whatever).

And another possibility without regex:

```
"(".join([x.rstrip() for x in my_string.split("(")])
```

(split the string according to `(`, then join it back with the same character applying a `rstrip()` within a list comprehension)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just:

```
re.sub(' +\(', '(', my_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, see my comment in the original post for selecting which solution to accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *lookahead assertion*, see the [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) in the Python documentation.

```
import re

my_string = 'log   (x)'
print(re.sub(r'\s+(?=\()', '', my_string))
# log(x)
```