# How to remove all words before specific word using Python (if there are multiple specific words)?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, postgresql

I want to remove all words before a specific word. But in my sentence there are some specific word. the following example:

```
dvdrentalLOG: statement: SELECT email, actor.last_name, count(actor.last_name) FROM (SELECT email, actor_id FROM (SELECT email, film_id FROM (SELECT email, inventory_id FROM customer as cu JOIN rental ON cu.customer_id = rental.customer_id ORDER BY email) as sq JOIN inventory ON sq.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id) as sq2 JOIN film_actor ON sq2.film_id = film_actor.film_id) as sq3 JOIN actor ON sq3.actor_id = actor.actor_id GROUP BY email, actor.last_name ORDER BY COUNT(actor.last_name) DESC
```

In the example above, I want to remove all the words before the *first* SELECT. I've already tried this [How to remove all characters before a specific character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30945784/10907221)

Any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex and replace with empty string:

```
^.+?(?=SELECT)
```

like this:

```
result = re.sub(r"^.+?(?=SELECT)", "", your_string)
```

Explanation:

Because you want to remove everything that's before the first `SELECT`, the match is going to start at the start of the string `^`. And then you lazily match any character `.+?`, until you see `SELECT`.

Alternatively, remove the lookahead and replace with `SELECT`:

```
result = re.sub(r"^.+?SELECT", "SELECT", your_string)
```

EDIT:

I found yet another way to do this, with [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
partitions = your_string.partition("SELECT")
result = partitions[1] + partitions[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned only with 1st occurence of word it is easy to do. Consider following example

```
import re
txt = 'blah blah blah SELECT something SELECT something another SELECT'
output = re.sub(r'.*?(?=SELECT)','',txt,1)
print(output) #SELECT something SELECT something another SELECT
```

I used so called zero-length assertion inside pattern, so it is match only if `SELECT` follow and I give `1` as 4th `re.sub` argument meaning that there will be only 1 substitution.