# Removing unecessary HTML before JSON

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I would like to remove the unecessary HMTL before the JSON data. The data has been scraped with Requests.
I've tried converting the `Requests` response to text and then stripping all the characters before `{` using the solutions suggested in [this question][1] but they don't work.

```
 r = r.text
 r = r.lstrip('{')
```

Sample response r:

```
 <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 10 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 19 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 3 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 21 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 11 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 2 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 20 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 9 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 5 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 4 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 22 in <b>/home/laziomar.it/public_html/components/com_laziomar/controllers/backendclient.php</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
    {"success":true,"message":null,"messages":null,"data":{"return":true,"output":[{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"10","id_porto_partenza":"4","id_porto_arrivo":"2","porto_partenza":"ANZIO","porto_arrivo":"PONZA","descrizione":"ANZIO-PONZA UV"},"corse":[]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"1","id_porto_partenza":"1","id_porto_arrivo":"2","porto_partenza":"FORMIA","porto_arrivo":"PONZA","descrizione":"FORMIA-PONZA"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6337,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"17:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6267,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"09:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6315,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"17:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6251,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"09:00:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6316,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"17:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6268,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"09:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"19","id_porto_partenza":"1","id_porto_arrivo":"2","porto_partenza":"FORMIA","porto_arrivo":"PONZA","descrizione":"FORMIA-PONZA UV"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6283,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6284,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6285,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6306,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6286,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6287,"data":"2021-10-11","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"3","id_porto_partenza":"1","id_porto_arrivo":"5","porto_partenza":"FORMIA","porto_arrivo":"VENTOTENE","descrizione":"FORMIA-VENTOTENE"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6081,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6099,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6128,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6082,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6083,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6084,"data":"2021-10-11","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"21","id_porto_partenza":"1","id_porto_arrivo":"5","porto_partenza":"FORMIA","porto_arrivo":"VENTOTENE","descrizione":"FORMIA-VENTOTENE UV"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6137,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"18:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6111,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"11:15:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6138,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"18:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6139,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"18:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6123,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6140,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"18:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"11","id_porto_partenza":"2","id_porto_arrivo":"4","porto_partenza":"PONZA","porto_arrivo":"ANZIO","descrizione":"PONZA-ANZIO UV"},"corse":[]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"2","id_porto_partenza":"2","id_porto_arrivo":"1","porto_partenza":"PONZA","porto_arrivo":"FORMIA","descrizione":"PONZA-FORMIA"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6404,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6367,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"05:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6417,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6345,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"05:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6405,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6346,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"05:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"20","id_porto_partenza":"2","id_porto_arrivo":"1","porto_partenza":"PONZA","porto_arrivo":"FORMIA","descrizione":"PONZA-FORMIA UV"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6376,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6377,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6378,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6398,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"10:00:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6379,"data":"2021-10-11","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6380,"data":"2021-10-12","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"9","id_porto_partenza":"2","id_porto_arrivo":"3","porto_partenza":"PONZA","porto_arrivo":"TERRACINA","descrizione":"PONZA-TERRACINA"},"corse":[]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"5","id_porto_partenza":"3","id_porto_arrivo":"2","porto_partenza":"TERRACINA","porto_arrivo":"PONZA","descrizione":"TERRACINA-PONZA"},"corse":[]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"4","id_porto_partenza":"5","id_porto_arrivo":"1","porto_partenza":"VENTOTENE","porto_arrivo":"FORMIA","descrizione":"VENTOTENE-FORMIA"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6213,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6197,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6221,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"12:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6244,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"17:30:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6198,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6199,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"22","id_porto_partenza":"5","id_porto_arrivo":"1","porto_partenza":"VENTOTENE","porto_arrivo":"FORMIA","descrizione":"VENTOTENE-FORMIA UV"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6168,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"06:45:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6228,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"16:15:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6169,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"06:45:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6170,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"06:45:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6229,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"16:15:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6190,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"09:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true}]}]}}


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945784/how-to-remove-all-characters-before-a-specific-character-in-python
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try out `str.split()` method.

Example: (should work as is)

```py
def get_json_string(s):
    return s.split("<br />")[-1].strip().split("\n")[0]
```

```py
>>> print(get_json_string(s))
{"success":true,"message":null,"messages":null,"data":{"return":true,"output":[{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"10","id_porto_partenza":"4","id_porto_arrivo":"2","porto_partenza":"ANZIO","porto_arrivo":"PONZA","descrizione":"ANZIO-PONZA UV"},"corse":[]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"1","id_porto_partenza":"1","id_porto_arrivo":"2","porto_partenza":"FORMIA","porto_arrivo":"PONZA","descrizione":"FORMIA-PONZA"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6337,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"17:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6267,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"09:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6315,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"17:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6251,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"09:00:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6316,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"17:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6268,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"09:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"19","id_porto_partenza":"1","id_porto_arrivo":"2","porto_partenza":"FORMIA","porto_arrivo":"PONZA","descrizione":"FORMIA-PONZA UV"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6283,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6284,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6285,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6306,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6286,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6287,"data":"2021-10-11","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-PONZA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"3","id_porto_partenza":"1","id_porto_arrivo":"5","porto_partenza":"FORMIA","porto_arrivo":"VENTOTENE","descrizione":"FORMIA-VENTOTENE"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6081,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6099,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6128,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6082,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6083,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6084,"data":"2021-10-11","partenza_ora":"09:15:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"21","id_porto_partenza":"1","id_porto_arrivo":"5","porto_partenza":"FORMIA","porto_arrivo":"VENTOTENE","descrizione":"FORMIA-VENTOTENE UV"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6137,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"18:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6111,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"11:15:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6138,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"18:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6139,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"18:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6123,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6140,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"18:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV FORMIA-VENTOTENE","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"11","id_porto_partenza":"2","id_porto_arrivo":"4","porto_partenza":"PONZA","porto_arrivo":"ANZIO","descrizione":"PONZA-ANZIO UV"},"corse":[]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"2","id_porto_partenza":"2","id_porto_arrivo":"1","porto_partenza":"PONZA","porto_arrivo":"FORMIA","descrizione":"PONZA-FORMIA"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6404,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6367,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"05:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6417,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6345,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"05:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6405,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"14:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6346,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"05:30:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"150","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"20","id_porto_partenza":"2","id_porto_arrivo":"1","porto_partenza":"PONZA","porto_arrivo":"FORMIA","descrizione":"PONZA-FORMIA UV"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6376,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6377,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6378,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6398,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"10:00:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6379,"data":"2021-10-11","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6380,"data":"2021-10-12","partenza_ora":"07:45:00","nave":"AGOSTINO LAURO","tempo_percorrenza":"80","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV PONZA-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"9","id_porto_partenza":"2","id_porto_arrivo":"3","porto_partenza":"PONZA","porto_arrivo":"TERRACINA","descrizione":"PONZA-TERRACINA"},"corse":[]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"5","id_porto_partenza":"3","id_porto_arrivo":"2","porto_partenza":"TERRACINA","porto_arrivo":"PONZA","descrizione":"TERRACINA-PONZA"},"corse":[]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"4","id_porto_partenza":"5","id_porto_arrivo":"1","porto_partenza":"VENTOTENE","porto_arrivo":"FORMIA","descrizione":"VENTOTENE-FORMIA"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6213,"data":"2021-10-06","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":false},{"id_corsa":6197,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6221,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"12:00:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6244,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"17:30:00","nave":"DON FRANCESCO","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6198,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6199,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"15:00:00","nave":"TETIDE","tempo_percorrenza":"120","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/04 - 31\/10 NAVE VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true}]},{"tratta":{"id_tratta":"22","id_porto_partenza":"5","id_porto_arrivo":"1","porto_partenza":"VENTOTENE","porto_arrivo":"FORMIA","descrizione":"VENTOTENE-FORMIA UV"},"corse":[{"id_corsa":6168,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"06:45:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6228,"data":"2021-10-07","partenza_ora":"16:15:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6169,"data":"2021-10-08","partenza_ora":"06:45:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6170,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"06:45:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6229,"data":"2021-10-09","partenza_ora":"16:15:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true},{"id_corsa":6190,"data":"2021-10-10","partenza_ora":"09:00:00","nave":"LAURA","tempo_percorrenza":"70","ritardo":"0","imbarco":"0","partenza":"0","flag_sospeso":"0","id_tariffa":"1","tariffa":"ORDINARIO","listino":"PERIODO 01\/01 - 31\/12 UV VENTOTENE-FORMIA","note":[],"bookable":true}]}]}}
```