# Regex to get all items between '#' and unknown character

Tags: python

I have a string that will have a value somewhere along the lines of

```
#549382This/ *is a test&
```

And I want to remove the `#549382` from the text.

I know there are a lot of questions about regex and I have looked at [this one specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945784/how-to-remove-all-characters-before-a-specific-character-in-python) which would work if I knew the character to remove. But any letter or symbol can follow that string of numbers. I need a way to be able to say

*Give me all characters between the '#' and the first letter*

What the letter is does not matter but it can be any non-digit character or letter.

---

For example

```
#549382This is a test         ->    This is a test
#71290571Another test here    ->    Another test here
#276//a comment as well       ->    //a comment as well
```

Comment: by "any alphabetical number" you mean "any non-digit character," yes?

Comment: Yes I do. I will edit the post to include that

Comment: regex is your friend

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to remove everything before the text, as your examples imply, or get the number between the # and the text, as your title and description imply.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you want "all the characters **between** the # and the first non-digit character" but your examples do not reflect this.

Comment: Either one works, if I get them then I can match and remove them using .replace. If I can remove them using regex that also works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your question, 'Give me all characters between the '#' and the first letter what the letter is does not matter but it can be any alphabetical number, meaning any non-digit character.', the following code will do:

```
import re

cases = [
    "#549382This is a test",
    "#71290571Another test",
    "#276//a comment as well",
]
regex_pattern = '#(\d+)'
for case in cases:
    number = re.findall(regex_pattern, case)
    print(number)

>>> ['549382']
>>> ['71290571']
>>> ['276']
```

Explaination: The regex will all digits `(\d+)` after the `#` and up to any non-digit character.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. can put it in a loop or whatever

```
import re
teststr='#549382This is a test'

e='#[0-9]*(.*)'

re.findall(e,teststr)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex like this

```
import re
string = '#549382This is a test'
result = re.sub('^#\d*', '', string)
This is a test
```